# Running external process as non blocking Java

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I am using JUnit to run a number of tests which require an external server (tomcat) to be running. I am currently using the following code to start tomcat.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("{path to tomcat}/bin/startup.bat");
            } catch (IOException exception) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
```

The issue come when all tests a complete, the JVM hangs waiting for tomcat to be closed. If I close tomcat manually the JVM closes as expected.

Is there a way to run tomcat such that once all test are complete (all other threads end) the JVM is not blocked and shuts down?

Answer (score 1):

In this case ending the thread which you used to execute the `startup.bat` batch script won't end the tomcat server. The solution:

---

### Short explanation:

You need to execute `shutdown.bat` to stop tomcat.

---

### Long explanation:

If you look at `startup.bat` line `56`, you'll see that the script runs the command `call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`. `%EXECUTABLE%` is set in line `38`: `set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"`. And if you look at `catalina.bat`, you'll see that after setting some standard variables and checking arguments, in line `242` (`if ""%1"" == ""start"" goto doStart`) it jumps to `:doStart`, which is located in line `279` doing some shifting magic to the arguments and setting `_EXECJAVA` to `start [...]` it finally executes whatever is inside `%_EXECJAVA%`. In case of starting this would be something involving the `start` command. As you can see from [this documentation of the `start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

> *Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)*

So essentially what the process that you're starting is doing is running the script, which *starts another program* and then *ends*, which automatically *ends* your process and allows the thread to finish. In fact you don't have direct control over tomcat, you can only use the scripts inside the `bin` directory.

---

### Conclusion:

So it should be easy to just do the following at the end of your program (you could possibly use a shutdown hook):

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("{path to tomcat}/bin/shutdown.bat");
            } catch (IOException exception) {
            }
        }
    });
```

So you run `startup.bat` to start tomcat and `shutdown.bat` to end it.

*Sorry for answering to an old question.*

Comment: This seems to be a good answer, to be honest I dont remember why we didnt do this in the first place. Today we are currently using [link](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) which allows us to have better control as to what gets deployed into the tomcat (having different tests deploying different war files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty the inputstream from the process or it will act "weird" when it fills the buffer size. Assuming `p` is the process returned by .exec():

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String in;
while ((in = br.readLine()) != null);
```

You can change the while loop to add { } and actually print the tomcat output if you'd like, but really all you need is to empty the buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Even you are not able to solve the issue with @Xabster answer there is an additional thing that you have to redirect error stream to input stream as well like this

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(prepareCommand(table));
ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new nputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String readLine = null;
while((readLine = stream.readLine()) != null){
    // you can do anything you want with what you read from stream
}
```